# Define all the fields in proto? Can it ignore undefined fields?

Tags: javascript, node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am following the tutorial from http://www.grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/node.html#try-it-out

I wantd to test how grpc handles undefined field from the protocol buffer so I modified the [route_guide_server.js](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.2.0/examples/node/dynamic_codegen/route_guide/route_guide_server.js), line 74, to return an additional field `test`

```
feature = {
    name: name,
    location: point,
    test: 'test'
  };
  return feature;
}
```

And then I got this error in the client side
`{ Error: .routeguide.Feature#test is not a field: undefined`

Is this the expected behavior? In my understanding from [protocol buffer doc](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#unknowns), unknown fields should be simply not serialized instead of throwing error?

Answer (score 0):

Protobuf only drops fields on deserialization, not serialization.  You can see the difference more clearly if you make you client and server use slightly different versions of the same proto.  The client should include the test field, but the server should not.